# Cron Expression for monthly job

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I want run scheduler job 14th of each month, if this day falls on a weekend, scheduler job should be day prior to this day. What is the cron expression for this?.

Comment: You should handle this in your job.You can not do this kind of exceptions in cron.

Comment: @selman is correct, further more you can visit this [web](https://crontab.guru/) and try out a few combination to fit your need.

Comment: @selman yes we cannot add this kind of expression in cron as we dont have flexible to add condition over cron. I think we can go with calling script or it should be handled in Java as below.

We should write the cron to pick job on 12th and from java side we need add below condition:
1. If 12 falls on Friday, the continue with other process.
2. If 12 falls on Thursday, then change fireTime to 13.
3. If 12 falls on Wednesday, then change fireTime to 14.

Please suggest me if you have any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you could extend [CronTriggerImpl](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/impl/triggers/CronTriggerImpl.html) to create a `NotOnWeekendsCronTrigger`. Eg:

```
public class NotOnWeekendsCronTrigger extends CronTriggerImpl {
    public Date getFireTimeAfter(Date afterTime) {
       return weekdayBefore(super.getFireTimeAfter(afterTime));
    }
    public Date getNextFireTime() {
       return weekdayBefore(super.getNextFireTime());
    }
    protected Date weekdayBefore(Date date) {
       // TODO implement
    }
    // etc etc
}
```